# A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1

Tags: java, json, swing, jsp

I am new to both JSON and JSP. I am writing a REST url, that will be called from a java swing application. the url will display some JSON data.
below is my jsp code:

```
JSONObject MainObject=null;
  JSONObject json1=null;
  JSONArray jarr=new JSONArray();

  String email = request.getParameter("EMAIL");

  cc = new MySQLConnection();

String query = "SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE EMAIL = '"+email+"'";
try{
conn =cc.db();
stmtt =conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);  
if(rs.next()){
    json1 = new JSONObject();
    MainObject = new JSONObject();

    json1.put("EMAIL", rs.getString("EMAIL"));
    json1.put("ID", rs.getLong("ID"));
    json1.put("COMPANY", rs.getString("COMPANY"));
    json1.put("CODE", rs.getString("CODE"));
    json1.put("VALID_TILL", rs.getLong("VALID_TILL"));
    jarr.put(json1);

    MainObject.put("SUCCESS", "1");
    MainObject.put("CLIENTS", jarr); 

    }
//else{
//out.println("Error....");
//}
    out.println(MainObject);
}

catch(SQLException ex){out.println(ex);}
finally{try{stmtt.close(); rs.close();conn.close();} catch(SQLException ex){out.println(ex);} }
```

This gives me the following output: `{"SUCCESS":"1","CLIENTS":[{"VALID_TILL":20,"COMPANY":"BOOK PALACE","ID":1,"EMAIL":"pranjal","CODE":"98877655"}]}`

Now when I try to parse the data from Swing application: it gives me error. I am parsing like this:

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EMAIL", mail)) ;
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(YOURUrl, "GET", params);
            System.out.println(json.toString());
             try {
                int success = json.getInt("SUCCESS");                

                if (success == 1) {
                    products = json.getJSONArray("CLIENTS");                   
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        String Company = c.getString("COMPANY");
                        String Name = c.getString("C_NAME");
                        String Email = c.getString("EMAIL");
                        String Code = c.getString("CODE");
                        String ValidTill = c.getString("VALID_TILL");
                        String sl = c.getString("ID");
                        COMPANY = Company;
                        CNAME = Name;
                        EMAIL = Email;
                        CODE = Code;
                        VALID_TILL = ValidTill;
                        SL = sl;

                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
```

What is the error in my jsp file?  Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what, pray tell, is the error trace?

Comment: And what does the System.out.println(json.toString()) print? Or does it not get that far? If not, try the request from a browser or the command line using telnet, curl, etc.

Comment: Obligatory "You code is vulnerable to sql injection" comment. Btw, my email is `'||(delete from clients)||'`

Comment: From browser it gives me `{"SUCCESS":"1","CLIENTS":[{"VALID_TILL":20,"COMPANY":"BOOK PALACE","ID":1,"EMAIL":"pranjal","CODE":"98877655"}]}`